# QGIS pyqgis custom/standalone script QSQLITE driver not loaded

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, mac

I'm using PyQGIS/Python 2.7 on a Mac and trying to create a script (for the first time) which will read in a list of csv files and load them as layers. I'll want to define the style of the layers and then display them in the QGIS canvas.  I am at the beginning stages of writing my script, **shown below**, and am executing it line-by-line using ipython.  When I execute the `app.initQgis()` line, I get

```
    QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded  
    QSqlDatabase: available drivers:   
    ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED  
    QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open  
    WARNING: Auth db query exec() FAILED
```

and when I execute the `app.exitQgis()` line, I get

```
    ERROR: Opening of authentication db FAILED
```

Is this some error/warning I should be concerned with and how do I fix this? I do not get the above responses when I execute these lines in the QGIS console.

Here is my script so far:

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)

app.initQgis()

csv_filename = "/myDataPath/modRes_All_d20141118_t1813404_e1815046.csv"
uri = csv_filename + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("\t", "lon", "lat")
csv_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "csvmodRes", "delimitedtext")
if not csv_layer:
   print "CSV Layer failed to load!"
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(csv_layer)

app.exitQgis()
```